# Bash Save & Load Arrays from file

Tags: bash

I am saving my global variable arrays to a file with this:

```
declare -p hashTable  > $File
declare -p testArray >> $File
```

I would like to load them back to global variables. I was using this:

```
source $File
```

That is fine when called from the global scope, but when it is within a function, it loads the variables back as local.

Is there a way to load them to globals?
Is there a way to save with the -g option so it loads globally?

Comment: `declare` was never designed to be a (de)serialization tool. You are better off using a different language if you want this type of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My two cents:

There are 2 way of doing this:

1. use `-g` argument of `declare` command

   ```
   declare -p hashTable testArray | sed 's/ -[aA]/&g/' >$File
   ```

   Nota: I prefer using `sed` when writting  *`$File`*, instead of when reading.

   ```
   fn() { source $File; }
   ```
2. declaring *global* variable out of the scope of function:

   ```
   declare -p hashTable testArray | sed 's/^.* -[aA] //' >$File
   ```

   then now:

   ```
   fn() { source $File; }
   declare -A hashTable
   declare -a testArray
   fn
   ```

   If *Associative array* are declared **before** function and `declare` command are not used in the scope of function, this will do the job.

Comment: Nota: `source` could by written `.`:  `fn() { . $File; }`.

Comment: I also prefer injecting the -g switch on writing the file. I will use `declare -p hashTable | sed '1s/^declare -[aA]/&g/'  > $File` to inject it only on the first line, and append the others the same way.

Answer (score 2):

On BASH 4.2+, you can source script as this inside your function:

```
fn() {
   source <(sed 's/^declare -[aA]/&g/' "$File")
}

# access your array outside the function
declare -p testArray
```

This `sed` will find lines starting with `declare -a` or `declare -A` and replace them with `declare -ag` thus making all the array as **global**.

Comment: Note this can break in extreme cases, such as if `\ndeclare -a` is part of the value of an array element.

Comment: Unavoidable corner cases aside, you might want to make it `-[aA]` to handle associative arrays as well.

Comment: 1st: `declare -p hashTable testArray | sed 's/ -[aA]/&g/' >$File`, then no need to use `sed` again... I won't post this: +1 for `g` switch!

Comment: and *declare* in `s/declare -[aA]` is useless, as `sed` will consider 1st occurence of *space - aA*.

Comment: @F.Hauri Could you clarify what you mean by "declare... is useless".  I can't follow what by "...space - aA"

Comment: writting `sed -e 's/-[aA]/&g/'` is enough, because sed will stop at 1st match.

Comment: Better to be safe than getting unexpected effects. `/^declare -[aA]/` makes sure to match lines that **start** with `declare -a` or `declare -A` only. If you also have simple variable declarations like this in file `declare -- s=" -a foo"` then `/ -[aA]/` will change value of the variable to make it  `declare -- s=" -ag foo"`